# Reusable views method for multiple model classes Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-urls

Guys I want to create a tools inventory app.

I have this method that will do the exact same thing on all tools types. What I want to know is how can I use this method dynamically selecting what models to use (maybe how to pass a model class as an argument).

It's currently working only for one type of tool. My **models.py** has an abstract model that has all common fields for all tools and then various models that inherit it for tool specific fields (e.i. End mills, Drill-bits, pliers, screwdrivers, etc all inherit common filed from my abstract model).

```
def calcular_nueva_cantidad(ce, up, get_link):

    if get_link == 'incremento':
        total = ce + up
    else:
        total = -(ce - up)
    return total

def calcular_nuevo_total(nce, pu):
    total = nce * pu
    return total


# crea el formulario para la actualizacion de cantidad existente
class updateForm(forms.Form):
    update = forms.IntegerField()


def actualizar_cantidad(request, pk, model ):
    # trae de la base de datos el valor de la cantidad_existente 
    cantidad_existente = model.objects.filter(pk=pk).values('cantidad_existente')
    c = cantidad_existente.values_list('cantidad_existente', flat=True)
    ce = c[0]
    # trae de la base de datos el valor de la precio_unitario 
    precio_unitario = model.objects.filter(pk=pk).values('precio_unitario')
    p = precio_unitario.values_list('precio_unitario', flat=True)
    pu = p[0]
    # trae de la base de datos el valor de la total
    qs_total = model.objects.filter(pk=pk).values('total')
    if request.method =='POST':
        form = updateForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            # Obtiene el name de urls para el link segun sea el caso
            get_link = resolve(request.path_info).url_name
            get_linkwargs = resolve(request.path_info).kwargs
            print(F'========>{get_link, get_linkwargs }<=========')

            up = form.cleaned_data['update']
            # Calcula el nuevo valor de cantidad existente 
            nce = calcular_nueva_cantidad(up, ce, get_link)

            # Actualiza la nueva cantidad existente  
            cantidad_existente.update(cantidad_existente=nce)

            # Calcula el nuevo valor de cantidad existente 
            s_total = calcular_nuevo_total(nce, pu)
            # Actualiza la nueva cantidad existente 
            qs_total.update(total=s_total)

            # Obteiene item id del tipo de cortador asi puede regresar a la pantalla del listado
            pp = model.objects.filter(pk=pk).values('tipo')
            ppp = pp.values_list('tipo', flat=True)
            pk = ppp[0]

            return  HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('inventario:cortadores-list', args=(pk, )))

        else:
            # Redirect to fail page after POST
            return HttpResponse('')
    else:
        form = updateForm()

    return render(request, 'inventario/update.html', {'form':form})
```

This is my **abstract** class in my **models.py**

```
class Item(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=30,)
    numero_parte = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    proveedor = models.ForeignKey(Proveedor, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cantidad_existente = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    update = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, default=0)
    cantidad_minima = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    precio_unitario = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)
    total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2, blank=True)
    asignado_a = models.ForeignKey(Empleados, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    anaquel = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=ANAQUEL, blank=True, null=True)
    posicion_en_x = models.CharField(max_length=2, blank=True, null=True)
    posicion_en_y = models.CharField(max_length=2, blank=True, null=True)
    activo = models.BooleanField()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True



    def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
        self.total = self.cantidad_existente * self.precio_unitario
        super().save(*args,**kwargs)
```

These two classes inherit from **Item**

```
class Cortadores(Item):
    tipo = models.ForeignKey(Tipos_Cortadores,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    material = models.ForeignKey(Materiales, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    filos = models.CharField(max_length=5, choices=GABILANES)
    diametro = models.ForeignKey(Diametros, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    longitud = models.ForeignKey(Longitud, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    desbaste = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=DESBASTE)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Cortadores"

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('inventario:cortadores-list', kwargs={'id': self.tipo.id})

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s %s %s %s %s' % (  str(self.tipo), str(self.material), str(self.filos), str(self.diametro), 
                                        self.longitud, self.desbaste
                                        )


class Tornillos(Item):
    tipo =  models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=TIPO_TORNILLO)
    paso = models.ForeignKey(Paso_Tornillo, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    material = models.ForeignKey(Materiales, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    longitud = models.ForeignKey(Longitud, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Tornillos"


    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('inventario:lista-herramientas-mecanicas')#, kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s %s %s' % (str(self.tipo), str(self.paso), str(self.material), str(self.longitud))
```

I made a class for every tool type that I own. I only included these two classes for simplicity and not fill the post with a lot of code.

Comment: We would need to see your abstract model, because depending on which fields are common this can be easy or complicated.

Comment: Thanks @Ralf, yesterday I tried 


`get_link = resolve(request.path_info).url_name`
so i could get the link name and use it in my  `calcular_nueva_cantidad(ce,up, get_link)`  so depending on the link name I could add or substract.

Comment: while i was reading about the resolve method  i noticed i could get the kwargs from url so I tryed inmy code this variable  `get_linkwargs = resolve(request.path_info).kwargs`
print(F'====>{get_link, get_linkwargs }<========')`
an noticed it worked  it was returning  
`====>('incremento', {'pk': 12, 'model': <class 'inventario.models.Cortadores'>})<========`. So i tried using this urlconf 
`path('nuevos-articulos/herramientas-de-corte/categoria-cortadores/<int:pk>/inc/', views.actualizar_cantidad, {'model':Cortadores}, name='incremento' ),`

Comment: And passing **model** as argument for `actualizar_cantidad(request, pk , model)`. It works for cortadores. How can I extend this functionality? how can I simplify this url so i can use it multiple times ? or is this even the best approach for this?

Comment: I added an answer with a different approach (using multi-table-inheritance). Maybe I think of another solution later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you still can change the design of your tables, you could use [multi-table-inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance) instead of the [abstract-base-class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes) you are using now.

That would mean that you will have one model `Item` (which will be an actual database table) and then other models that inherit from this model (their database tables will only hold the new fields, but not repeat any fields).

For that change you only need to remove `abstract = True` from `Item.Meta`; you should not need to change other parts form your models. Of course, you will have to drop your tables and run migrations again (will destroy your current data).

As I said, this is only an option if you can still change your database tables significantly.

---

With this setup, you can query your `Item` model directly for the common fields. There are some subtleties you have to be careful about, but read the docs I linked to see if it solves your issue.